# How to create a SQL function to parse multiple xml formatted strings?

Tags: sql, function, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a price from a price column in SQL.  I have already create a function that will parse the price but it only works if "all" price strings are the same on all items.  I realize now that I need a more robust function that can parse out multiple price configuration.

Here is my simple SQL query

```
I.[NAME] AS 'ITEM NAME'
,DBO.parsePrice(I.PRICING) AS 'ITEM PRICE'
FROM ITEM I
order by 'ITEM NAME'
```

Here is my function DBO.parsePrice

```
RETURNS decimal(8,2) AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(@in AS XML).value(N'(/prices[@type="Level"]/item[@level="A"])[1]/@price', N'DECIMAL(14,2)');
END
```

Here is the XML string with just one price level.

```
<prices type="Level"><item level="A" price="10.00" /></prices>
```

The function will output 10.00 from the string above.

Here is another example with a max of 6 different price levels

```
<prices type="Level"><item level="A" price="10.00" /><item level="B" price="11.00" /><item level="C" price="12.00" /><item level="D" price="13.00" /><item level="E" price="14.00" /><item level="F" price="15.00" /></prices>
```

My function was only designed to parse out price level (A).  To make things even more complicated the price string can also be configured with different order types rather than price levels.

```
<prices type="OrderType"><item level="DineIn" price="7" /><item level="TakeOut" price="8.00" /><item level="Delivery" price="" /><item level="Sale" price="" /></prices>
```

The new function needs to handle all these different situations.  Ideally, I would like to have separate columns for each price break rather than a field that has the prices comma separated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards,

JC

The above SQL query was just an example for posting the question.  My actual query is pulling data from other tables using left joins.

```
SELECT
I.[NAME] AS 'ITEM NAME'
,DBO.parsePrice(I.PRICING) AS 'ITEM PRICE'
,ML.NAME AS 'MODIFIER LIST NAME'
,MG.NAME AS 'MODIFIER GROUP NAME'
,M.NAME AS 'MODIFIER NAME'
,M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION AS UPCHARGE
FROM ITEM I
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ITEM_MODIFIER] IM ON IM.ITEM_RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_LIST] ML ON ML.RECORD_KEY = IM.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_GROUP] MG ON MG.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY = ML.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER] M ON M.MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY = MG.RECORD_KEY
order by 'ITEM NAME'
```

Comment: You may wish to return a table of (level, price).

Comment: This was just a simple query.  My actual query is pulling data from other tables that uses left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a TVF returning (level, price)

```
create function DBO.parsePrice(@x xml)
returns table
return
select p.n.value('@level', 'nvarchar(100)') level, p.n.value('@price', 'decimal(9,2)') price
from @x.nodes('prices/item') p(n)
```

and use it in the query

```
SELECT
I.[NAME] AS 'ITEM NAME'
, p.*
,ML.NAME AS 'MODIFIER LIST NAME'
,MG.NAME AS 'MODIFIER GROUP NAME'
,M.NAME AS 'MODIFIER NAME'
,M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION AS UPCHARGE
FROM ITEM I
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ITEM_MODIFIER] IM ON IM.ITEM_RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_LIST] ML ON ML.RECORD_KEY = IM.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_GROUP] MG ON MG.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY = ML.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER] M ON M.MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY = MG.RECORD_KEY
CROSS APPLY DBO.parsePrice(I.PRICING) p
order by 'ITEM NAME', p.Level
```

**EDIT**

Following OP remarks this is a version of the TVF which returns 0 for @price which is not numeric

```
create function DBO.parsePrice(@x xml)
returns table
return
select level, coalesce(try_cast(price as decimal(9,2)),0) price
from (
   select p.n.value('@level', 'varchar(100)') level, p.n.value('@price', 'nvarchar(50)') price
   from @x.nodes('prices/item') p(n)
) t
```

Comment: This is the error that I am receiving  when running the above query

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Some @ prices in your xml are not representing decimal value. You need a logic in the function to deal with those non-numeric. Skip it, assume null, 0 or something.

Comment: I would like to give you credit for the solution.  I did modify what you provided to produce the results we are looking for. I updated @'level and @price to nvarchar(100) and nvarchar(50) respectively.  As well as the select statement to ,p.level, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(p.price) = 1 then CAST(p.price AS DECIMAL(18,2)) ELSE 0 END.  If you update your solution with these changes I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Serg, thank you for your help.  I was hoping that you could expand your solution to include parsing out the "Prices Type=Level" for example (Level, Order Type, etc).  It is one level up from "prices/item".  I would like to add this additional column to my query results.  I am able to display the type data by changing "from @x.nodes('prices/item')" to from @x.nodes('//prices') and adding to the select statement "p.n.value('@type', 'varchar(100)') type"but then I get nulls in the level and price columns.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Serg, I actually was able to figure this out.  Please see complete solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I have marked Serg solution as the correct one even though I had to make a couple changes to produce the results we were looking for without getting a data type conversion error. Here is the complete solution I am using.

SQL Query

```
SELECT
I.[NAME] AS 'ITEM NAME'
,ic.NAME AS 'ITEM CATEGORY'
,p.*
,ML.NAME AS 'MODIFIER LIST NAME'
,MG.NAME AS 'MODIFIER GROUP NAME'
,M.NAME AS 'MODIFIER NAME'
,M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION AS UPCHARGE
FROM ITEM I
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ITEM_MODIFIER] IM ON IM.ITEM_RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [DBO].[ITEM_CATEGORY] IC ON IC.RECORD_KEY = I.ITEM_CATEGORY_RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_LIST] ML ON ML.RECORD_KEY = IM.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER_GROUP] MG ON MG.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY = ML.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MODIFIER] M ON M.MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY = MG.RECORD_KEY
CROSS APPLY DBO.parsePrice(I.PRICING) p

/*where ml.name is not null*/
order by 'ITEM CATEGORY', 'ITEM NAME', P."Price TYPE", P."Price LEVEL"
```

Tabled_Valued Function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE function [dbo].[parsePrice](@x xml)
returns table
return
select "PRICE TYPE", "PRICE LEVEL", coalesce(try_cast("Item Price" as decimal(9,2)),0) "ITEM PRICE"
from (
   select t.n.value('@type', 'varchar(100)') "PRICE TYPE", p.n.value('@level', 'varchar(100)') "PRICE LEVEL", p.n.value('@price', 'nvarchar(50)') "ITEM PRICE"
   from @x.nodes('//prices') t(n), @x.nodes('prices/item') p(n)
) t
```